# How to setup HTTPS on an EC2 instance WITHOUT load balancer ? (aws)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I know that installing ssl and having https on a server is a piece of cake for you all, but still:
Can someone get me the solution for having HTTPS on a EC2 instance, without load balancer, on a AWS ec2 server.

thank you

Comment: have you had any luck?

Comment: What webserver are you using (i.e. Apache, Nginx, etc.)?

Comment: I am using Apache

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To setup Https on EC2 instance follow the below steps:

**Step 1: Allow HTTPS port on EC2 Instance**

- Go to your security group and select the security group applied to
  your instance.
- Select Inbound tab of the security group info.
- Click Edit.
- Click Add rule, choose Type: **HTTPS**.
- Click: **Save**.

**If you’re hosting DNS of your domain on AWS Route53, then you should also perform the below steps:**

**Select the appropriate Hosted Zone.**

- If you don’t have an A record for the app’s domain, click **Create
  Record Set and choose Type: A - IPv4 address**.
- In the Value Field, set the **Public IP address** of your EC2 instance.
- Otherwise, click on the A record for the app’s domain.
- Click Save **record set**.